# How to prove the only solution to $f(x)=f'(x)$ is $ce^x$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $\exp(x)$ is the only function for which $f(x) = f'(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/proof-that-expx-is-the-only-function-for-which-fx-fx)

I've learned from calculus that $Ce^x$ is a solution to the equation $f(x)=f'(x)$, where $C$ is a constant. However, in my Physics class the textbook takes it as the only solution to the equation without proof.

I wonder why there are no other solutions? I haven't taken the course of ODE, so I might need an elementary explanation~ Any help will be welcome~

Comment: An answer is given by a link on this page. Go to the right side, look for the question that asks about $\dfrac{df}{dx}=3f$.