# Proving that $f(x)=c \cdot e^x$ is the only function such that $f'(x)=f(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proof that $\exp(x)$ is the only function for which $f(x) = f'(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/proof-that-expx-is-the-only-function-for-which-fx-fx)

Here's a question I got for homework:

> Let f a differentiable function such that $f(x)=f'(x)$ for all $x$.
>   Prove that there exist a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = c \cdot
>  e^x$
>
> Hint: notice $\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}$

So, as it turns out this hint was not enough.

Any more hints? Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you differentiate $\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}$ with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT:

What's the derivative of $\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}$ (With the quotient rule, perhaps it's easier to see). Then what does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's a first-order linear ordinary differential equation.
To put it in a simple way, let $y=f(x)$.
Then
$$
         \frac{dy}{dx}=y.
$$
Hence,
$$
         \frac{dy}{y}=dx,
$$ 
(if $y$ doesn't equal $0$).

Integrating in both sides, we get
$$
         \ln|y|=x+c_1,
$$
where $c_1$ is a constant.
Therefore，
$$
         |y|=e^{x+c_1}=e^{c_1}*e^x.
$$
Let $|c|=e^{c_1}$, then we get 
$$
         y=c*e^x.
$$
If $y=0$, then it of course satisfies the condition.

Comment: Sorry for the bad notation. Just new here, and I am still learning how to use the mathematical notation in this website.

Comment: I found a useful way to see how people generate symbols here is to click edit and see how they write thing (while not editing the answer of course!)

Comment: @Holdsworth88: If you right-click on a formula, select *Show Math As*, and then select *TeX Commands*, you’ll get a pop-up window showing the $\LaTeX$ that was actually used.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Well, that simplifies that process a bit. Thank you for telling me about that feature.

Comment: @Holdsworth88@BrianM.Scott Thank you for telling me that.

Comment: What if $y$ is not the zero function but happens to take the value zero at some points? Also, the constant $c$ needn't be positive, though the argument seems to imply that it is.

Comment: @ Shane O Rourke The derivative of ln|y| is 1/y, so when you look back to the answer again which I have edited, you will find c can be negative. And it can't be the case that y happens to take the value zero at some points but not the zero function.(here y is continuous at every x)