# How to prove that if $ f(x) = f'(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = c e^x$

Tags: calculus

In calculus, If I know that a derivative of a function is the function itself, how do I prove that the function equals $e^x$:

$$
f(x) = f'(x) \Rightarrow f(x) = ce^x
$$
Why is this always true?

Thank you

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/proof-that-c-expx-is-the-only-set-of-functions-for-which-fx-fx/58098).

Comment: Hi, sorry was looking for the answer, didn't find the original question. Thanks!