# Why is $e^x$ the only nontrivial function with a repeating derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Why is $e^x$ the only nontrivial function with a repeating derivative, *i.e.* is  its own derivative?

It says so in the [Wikipedia article about $e$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29#Properties). Is there a proof of this that I (a calculus AB student) could understand? Thanks!

Comment: This will help:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/58097/35983

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically $y=0$ is also a function with a repeating derivative but in answer to your question, what you're essentially doing is solving the differential equation $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y$ to which the only non-trivial solution is $y=A e^x$. (The differential equation is not hard to solve)

Comment: Oh ok thanks I should've thought of that

Comment: no problem at all

Answer (score 4):

$y = A e^x$ is a solution of the linear differential equation
$$ y' = \frac{dy}{dx} = y $$
with an initital condition $y(0)=A$. By the [Picard-Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) there exists a unique solution to that equation with intial condition $y(0)=A$. For $A = 0$ you get the solution $y(x) = 0$ (the constant zero function) which trivially has a repeating derivative. For $A \ne 0$ you get the solution $y(x) = Ae^x = A \exp(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $y = f(x)$ be a function that satisfies the differential equation:
$$
\dfrac{dy}{dx} =y
$$

We will solve this ODE by separation of variables. Observe that this is equivalent to:
$$ \begin{align*}
\dfrac{1}{y}dy &= dx \\
\int \dfrac{1}{y}dy &= \int dx \\
\ln|y|&=x+C \\
|y|&=e^{x+C} \\
|y|&=e^Ce^{x} \\
y&=\pm e^Ce^{x} \\
y&=Ke^{x} \\
\end{align*} $$
where $K=\pm e^C$ is some constant. This proves that the only types of functions that are equal to their own derivative are functions that are scalar multiples of $y=e^x$.

Answer (score 0):

Since taking the derivative is a linear operator, we have for any constant $c$:
$$ (cf(x))' = cf'(x) $$
Thus for any solution $f(x)$ to your question, we would also have $cf(x)$.

Therefore without loss of generality (and assuming the $f(0) \ne 0 $) we can choose
$$f(0) = 1$$
Now the function is determined by the fact that the derivative is known, and you can make a computer plot the function as tiny linear segments with that slope. What you get is the exponential function.