# Use Constancy Theorem and Mean Value Theorem to Prove

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

if f'(x) =a f(x) for all x, then f(x) =A exp (ax) for some constant A；

Comment: "Constancy Theorem"?

Comment: Perhaps, see [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/proof-that-c-expx-is-the-only-set-of-functions-for-which-fx-fx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $G(x)=\frac{f(x)}{e^{ax}}$. Differentiate. The derivative simplifies a lot!