# Are the any non-trivial functions where $f(x)=f'(x)$ not of the form $Ae^x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, exponential-function

This may seem like a silly question, but I just wanted to check. I know there are proofs that if $f(x)=f'(x)$ then $f(x)=Ae^x$. But can we 'invent' another function that obeys $f(x)=f'(x)$ which is **non-trivial**?

Comment: How should such a function be invented? If you invent one, then $f=f'$ and by the proof you mentioned, then $f(x) = Ae^x$ must hold.

Comment: If you can prove that $f(x)=f'(x)$ implies $f(x)=Ae^x$, then logically any function that obeys $f(x)=f'(x)$ will have to be of the form $f(x)=Ae^x$. That might have sounded redundant, but that's what the implication means... unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: @LeBtz I don't know... It was inspired by another post which asked if there are any 'non-trivial' examples where it was true. I assumed that meant there were non-trivial examples.

Comment: If you allow for piecewise functions which are not everywhere differentiable, then there are many nontrivial functions of that form.

Comment: IMO you should accept the solution by k1.M. unless someone posts a better one. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Ryan a function that is not everywhere differentiable can hardly satisfy an equation involving its derivative.  But in fact any absolutely continuous function $f$ that satisfies $f' = f$ almost everywhere is of the form $A e^x$.

Comment: I've actually added a second answer despite having opined that you should accept someone else's answer!  Please at least look at it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I think English-speaking use the word "any" too much. "Any member of the club can become the next chairman" doesn't mean "Every member of the club can become the next chairman", and in the sentence "If there is any member who can do it, Robert can", the word "any" means something more like "some" than like "every", and the sentence "If anyone can do it, Robert can" is actually ambiguous. In the sentence "Any absolutely continuous function is purple", "any" might mean "every", but then someone adds "and if any absolutely continuous function is purple then...." and it's ambiguous.

Comment: . . . . so would you object to writing "But in fact every absolutely continuous function $f$ that satisfies $f'=f$ almost everywhere is of the form $Ae^x$"? ${}\qquad{}$ @RobertIsrael ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @RobertIsrael : TYPO: I _thought_ I'd written "English-speaking mathematicians" above.

Comment: @MichaelHardy You're quire right that the use of "any" can lead to ambiguities. In Robert Israel's comment, though, it does not; the comment is unambiguous and his use of "any" is fine.

Comment: @Robert Israel when you say *almost* anywhere what do you mean? Not including one or two undefined points?

Comment: Sorry, in my first comment I meant so say a post which asked whether there are any 'non-non-trivial' solutions other than $Ae^x$

Comment: Almost everywhere in the sense of Lebesgue measure.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere

Comment: @AndreasBlass : Certainly this particular instance is not ambigious, but "every" seems slightly more emphatic and if people would get out of the habit of using "any" so much, then those cases where it is ambiguous wouldn't happen as often as they do.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1764187/is-the-natural-logarithm-actually-unique-as-a-multiplier

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Observe that if $ f(x)=f'(x) $ then
$$
\left(\frac{f(x)}{e^x}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)-f(x)}{e^x}=0
$$
Hence $\dfrac{f(x)}{e^x}$ is constant...

Comment: @MichaelHardy: Thanks for the edit...

Comment: +1 and accepted. This is my favourite just because of its beautiful simplicity.

Comment: The method of the "integrating factor".  Every student of calculus should learn this,

Answer (score 13):

I think other answers given here assume the existence of a nice function $e^{x}$ and this makes the proof considerably simpler. However I believe that it is better to approach the problem of solving $f'(x) = f(x)$ without knowing anything about $e^{x}$.

When we go down this path our final result is the following:

> **Theorem**: *There exists a unique function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which is differentiable for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and satisfies $f'(x) = f(x)$ and $f(0) = 1$. Further any function $g(x)$ which is differentiable for all $x$ and satisfies $g'(x) = g(x)$ is explicitly given by $g(x) = g(0)f(x)$ where $f(x)$ is the unique function mentioned previously.*

We give a simple proof of the above theorem without using any properties/knowledge of $e^{x}$. Let's show that if such a function $f$ exists then it must be unique. Suppose there is another function $h(x)$ such that $h'(x) = h(x)$ and $h(0) = 1$. Then the difference $F(x) = f(x) - h(x)$ satisfies $F'(x) = F(x)$ and $F(0) = 0$. We will show that $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$. Suppose that it is not the case and that there is a point $a$ such that $F(a) \neq 0$ and consider $G(x) = F(a + x)F(a - x)$. Clearly we have
\begin{align}
G'(x) &= F(a - x)F'(a + x) - F(a + x)F'(a - x)\notag\\
&= F(a - x)F(a + x) - F(a + x)F(a - x)\notag\\
&= 0
\end{align}
so that $G(x)$ is constant for all $x$. Therefore $G(x) = G(0) = F(a) \cdot F(a) > 0$. We thus have $F(a + x)F(a - x) > 0$ and hence putting $x = a$ we get $F(2a)F(0) > 0$. This contradicts $F(0) = 0$.

It follows that $F(x) = 0$ for all $x$ and hence the function $f$ must be unique. Now we need to show the existence. To that end we first establish that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. If there is a number $b$ such that $f(b) = 0$ then we can consider the function $\phi(x) = f(x + b)$ and it will have the property that $\phi'(x) = \phi(x)$ and $\phi(0) = 0$. By argument in preceding paragraph $\phi(x)$ is identically $0$ and hence $f(x) = \phi(x - b)$ is also identically $0$. Hence it follows that $f(x)$ is non-zero for all $x$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous and $f(0) = 1 > 0$ it follows that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$.

Since $f'(x) = f(x) > 0$ for all $x$, it follows that $f(x)$ is strictly increasing and differentiable with a non-vanishing derivative. By inverse function therorem the inverse function $f^{-1}$ exists (if $f$ exists) and is also increasing with non-vanishing derivative. Also using techniques of differentiation it follows that $f'(x) = f(x)$ implies that $\{f^{-1}(x)\}' = 1/x$ for all $x > 0$ and $f^{-1}(1) = 0$. Since $1/x$ is continuous the definite integral $$\psi(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$$ exists for all $x > 0$ and has the properties of $f^{-1}$ and it is easy to show that $f^{-1}(x) = \psi(x)$. Clearly the function $(f^{-1}(x) - \psi(x))$ is constant as it derivative is $0$ and hence $$f^{-1}(x) - \psi(x) = f^{-1}(1) - \psi(1) = 0$$ so that $$f^{-1}(x) = \psi(x) = \int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t}$$ Next using inverse function theorem $f(x)$ exists. Thus the question of existence of $f(x)$ is settled.

Now consider $g(x)$ with $g'(x) = g(x)$. If $g(0) = 0$ then we know from argument given earlier that $g(x) = 0$ for all $x$. If $g(0) \neq 0$ then we study the function $\psi(x) = g(x)/g(0)$. Clearly $\psi'(x) = \psi(x)$ and $\psi(0) = 1$ and hence it is same as the unique function $f(x)$. Thus $g(x)/g(0) = \psi(x) = f(x)$ for all $x$. Hence $g(x) = g(0)f(x)$.

The unique function $f(x)$ in the theorem proved above is denoted by $\exp(x)$ or $e^{x}$.

Answer (score 8):

No. Suppose that $f \not\equiv 0$. We **solve** the ODE: $$f(x) = f'(x) \implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = 1 \implies \int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}\,{\rm d}x = \int \,{\rm d}x \implies \ln |f(x)| = x+c, \quad c \in \Bbb R$$With this, $|f(x)| = e^{x+c} = e^ce^x$. Call $e^c = A > 0$. Eliminating the absolute value, we have $f(x) = Ae^x$, with $A \in \Bbb R \setminus \{0\}$. Since $f \equiv 0$ also satisfies the equation, we can write all at once: $$f(x) = Ae^x, \quad A \in \Bbb R.$$

Comment: This does not tells the only solution for $\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} dx$ is $\ln|f(x)|$

Answer (score 8):

Consider $g(x) = f(x)\exp(-x)$. Then we have $g'(x) = f'(x)\exp(-x)-f(x)\exp(-x) = 0$. Thus, $g\equiv c$ for some constant $c$. Hence $f(x) = c\exp(x)$.

Answer (score 4):

You have $\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y$.  Often one writes $\dfrac{dy} y = dx$ and then evaluates both sides of $\displaystyle\int\frac{dy} y = \int dx$, etc.

However, for a question like this perhaps one should be more careful.

If $f(x)\ne 0$ for all $x$, then one has $\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=1$ for all $x$.  This implies
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \log |f(x)| = 1
$$
for all $x$.  The mean value theorem entails there can be no antiderivatives besides
$$
\log|f(x)| = x + \text{constant}
$$
for all $x$.  This implies $|f(x)| = e^x\cdot\text{a positive constant}$, so $f(x)=e^x\cdot\text{a nonzero constant}$.

Dividing by $f(x)$ assumes $f(x)$ is not $0$, so one has to check separately the case where $f(x)$ is everywhere $0$, and it checks.

Now what about cases where $f(x)=0$ for some $x$ but not all?  Can we rule those out?  We would have $f(x_0)=0$ and $f(x_1)\ne 1$.  Then one solution would be
$$
g(x) = f(x_1)e^{x-x_1} = f(x_1)e^{-x_1} e^x = A e^x.
$$
But $g(x_0)\ne0=f(x_0)$ and $g(x_1)=f(x_1)$ and $(f-g)'=f-g$ everywhere.

[to be continued, maybe${}\,\ldots\,{}$]

Comment: If $f(x)=0$ then $f'(x)=0$, so there is no problem at all

Comment: @AnalysisStudent0414 : If $f(x_0)=0$ then certainly $f'(x_0)=0$ so they're both $0$ at _one_ point.  Certainly the function that is _everywhere_ $0$ is a solution, but the question is how to prove that if a function satisfying this differential equation is _somewhere_ $0$ then it is _everywhere_ $0$. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

OK, let's try a plodding pedestrian approach:
$$
f'(x)-f(x) = 0
$$
The idea of an exponential multiplier $m(x)$ is that we write
$$
0 = m(x)f'(x) + (-m(x))f(x) = m(x)f'(x)+m'(x)f(x) = \Big( m(x)f(x)\Big)'.
$$
For this to work we would need $-m(x)=m'(x)$.  We **do not need *all*** functions $m$ satisfying this, but only one.  So there's no need to wonder whether any non-trivial solutions to $m'=-m$ exist; we only need a trivial one.  $m(x)=e^{-x}$ does it. So
$$
0 = \Big( m(x)f(x)\Big)'.
$$
Thus, by the mean value theorem, $m(x)f(x)$ is constant, so $f(x)=(\text{constant}\cdot e^x$).