# Proving that if $f'=cf$ on some interval then $f=ke^{cx}$ on the interval.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that on some interval the function $f$ satisfies $f'=cf$ for some number $c$.

(a) Assuming that $f$ is never $0$, prove that $|f(x)|=le^{cx}$ for some number $l\gt 0$. It follows that $f(x)=ke^{cx}$ for some $k$.

(b) Show that this result holds without the added assumption that $f$ is never $0$. Hint: Show that $f$ can't be $0$ at the endpoint of an open interval on which it is nowhere $0$.

(c) Suppose that $f'=fg'$ for some $g$. Show that $f(x)=ke^{g(x)}$ for some number $k$.

My work:

(a) is easy. For (b), first assume that $f$ does not vanish on the entire interval. Then $f(x_0)\neq 0$ for some point. Hence, by continuity there is some open interval around $x_0$ for which the function is nonzero, and hence by (a), $f(x)=ke^{cx}$. Now as the hint suggests, I want to prove that $f$ can't be $0$ at the endpoint of an open interval on which it is nowhere $0$. Again by continuity, the endpoint of this interval would be $w:=\sup\{x\gt x_0 : f(x)\neq 0\}$ and $z:=\inf\{x\lt x_0 : f(x)\neq 0\}$.

Here is where I'm struggling. I think that this $f$ can't be $0$ on both of these endpoints because $f$ is either always positive or always negative on this interval and since it is also continuous on the endpoints, it can't suddenly vanish at the point. However, I cannot precisely show this. How can I rigorously prove this idea?

Finally, for (c), solving differential equations I get $|f|=de^g$ for some number $d$. Again, to show that $f=ke^g$ on the interval, I need to show that $f$ is never $0$. However, unlike the situation in (b), I think since $g$ is also a function, it can rapidly go to $\infty$ as $x$ goes to the endpoint of the same proposed interval, and then $f$ can actually go to zero. How can I show that like (b), $f$ is never zero on the entire interval?

I would greatly appreciate any help for the above two questions.

Comment: A simple idea for c would be to define $h(x)=f(x)exp(-g(x))$, then derive it (you get $0$), and conclude that it is a constant :)

Comment: Yes that's a much simpler way, but I'm trying to work it through similar reasoning as in (b) and was wondering how it could be shown.

Comment: Why don't you use the existence and uniqueness theorem? :) Both (a) and (b) are easily can be solved using them. As for part (c), you should ask what restrictions are put on function $g(x)$.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out a way to solve this using only the idea in the hint.

Comment: Can you show how did you approach part (a) ?

Comment: @Vlad (a) was done as usual. Divide by $f$ and we get $(log|f|)'=c$, so $lof|f(x)|=cx+d$ for some number $d$, hence $|f(x)|=le^{cx}$ for some $l\gt 0$.

Comment: Can you tell me why you are so much focusing on the non-vanishing nature of $f$? As as I have shown in my answer there is no need to know whether $f$ vanishes or not in order to solve the problem. Perhaps you are too influenced by the technique of solving differential equations and you want to express your equation in the form $f'/f = c$ or $f'/f = g'$. This is not needed.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: I am not sure if OP is the downvoter. But I guess OP wants to complete his ongoing proof of this statement.

*If $f$ is continuous and differentiable on $[a, b]$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$ then $f(a) \neq 0 \neq f(b)$*.

Clearly this statement is wrong and counter examples abound. Check $f(x) = x(1 - x)$ on $[0, 1]$.

However the result holds for the specific function in question. Switching to the notations used by OP we have $f(x) = ke^{cx}$ on some interval $I$ and $z, w$ with $z < w$ are the end-points of this interval. Also $f$ is continuous on $[z, w]$ and $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in (z, w)$. This means that $k \neq 0$. Since $f(x) = ke^{cx}$ for all $x \in (z, w)$ it follows by continuity that $$f(z) = \lim_{x \to z^{+}}f(x) = \lim_{x \to z^{+}}ke^{cx} = ke^{cz} \neq 0$$ Similarly we can show that $f(w) \neq 0$. Nothing more than continuity of $f$ is required here.

---

Note that the question in part a) has a simple solution only when we know the properties of exponential and logarithmic functions. Without knowing anything about these functions it is bit hard to establish a) and this [has been done here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031).

Although it is not necessary to know whether $f$ vanishes or not (and I don't know why you want to deal with vanishing/non-vanishing of $f$) you can do it easily as follows.

For Part b) we have $f'(x) = cf(x)$ for all $x \in I$. If $c = 0$ then $f$ is a constant and hence if it vanishes at one point it vanishes for all $x \in I$. So let's assume that $c \neq 0$. Let $a \in I$ be such that $f(a) \neq 0$. Without any loss of generality we can assume that $a$ is an interior point of $I$ (because if $a$ were an end point then by continuity we could find an interior point nearby where $f$ is non-zero). We will show that $f(x) \neq 0$ for all $x \in I$. Consider the function $g(x) = f(a + x)f(a - x)$. Clearly since $a$ is interior point of $I$ the function $g$ is defined in some interval of type $[0, p)$. We can see that
\begin{align}
g'(x) &= f'(a + x)f(a - x) - f(a + x)f'(a - x)\notag\\
&= cf(a + x)f(a - x) - cf(a + x)f(a - x)\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
so that $g$ is a constant and thus $f(a + x)f(a - x) = g(x) = g(0) = \{f(a)\}^{2} > 0$. It follows that both $f(a + x), f(a - x)$ are non-zero for all $x \in [0, p)$. If $(a + p)$ (or $(a - p)$) is an interior of $I$ then we can continue the same argument by replacing $a$ with $(a + p)$ (or $(a - p)$) and thereby extend the region where $f$ does not vanish. Using the same argument repeatedly we can show that $f$ does not vanish at any point in $I$.

For part c) (which is similar to part a))we can consider the function $h(x) = f(x) / \exp(g(x))$. We have \begin{align}
h'(x) &= \frac{\exp(g(x))f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)\exp(g(x))}{\exp(2g(x))}\notag\\
&= \frac{f(x)g'(x)\exp(g(x)) - f(x)g'(x)\exp(g(x))}{\exp(2g(x))}\notag\\
& = 0\notag
\end{align}
and therefore $h(x) = k$ where $k$ is some constant number. It thus follows that $f(x) = k\exp(g(x))$. Note that this proof would be difficult (like proof of part a)) if we don't know anything about exponential and logarithmic functions.

**Note**: We don't need to know about vanishing / non-vanishing of $f$ (provided we know the properties of exponential and logarithmic functions). Thus for part a) we use $h(x) = f(x)/\exp(cx)$ and get $h'(x) = 0$ so that $h(x) = k$ and $f(x) = k\exp(cx)$.

Comment: Looks like someone's on a down voting spree. Let me know if there is some way I can improve my answer.

Comment: Just checked your answer, thanks it's brilliant!! But I was just wondering what the motivation was for coming up with such an answer in (b). How did you think of such a method?

Comment: @takecare: I already had used the same technique at http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031 It is a good technique and surprising if you see for the first time.

Comment: I just checked that post and it's amazing learned a lot from it!! I guess the motivation is to use the fact that the derivative becomes zero and it's value at 0 is a square. Where did you first encounter such a technique?

Comment: @takecare: While I was developing material for my blog posts on exponential and logarithmic functions (see http://paramanands.blogspot.com/2014/05/theories-of-exponential-and-logarithmic-functions-part-1.html) I was thinking of various possible approaches. One of them was to treat $e^{x}$ as the unique solution to $f'(x) = f(x), f(0) = 1$. And I needed to show that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x$. This is where I found the technique after a number of failed attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Considering $f'/f$ is fine for conjecturing the result, but dividing by $f$ makes too much complication. So, after guessing $f(x)=k\cdot  e^{g(x)}$, define 
$$
k(x) = f(x) \cdot e^{-g(x)}
$$
instead. (That function is conjectured to  be constant.) Then take its derivative:
$$
k'(x) = f'(x) \cdot e^{-g(x)} - f(x) \cdot e^{-g(x)}g'(x) = 
(f'(x) - f(x)g'(x)) \cdot  e^{-g(x)} =  0.
$$
Therefore, $k(x)$ is constant.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to see an answer that shows in (b) and (c), $f$ can't be $0$ in an open interval on which it is nowhere zero.

Comment: If you assume that $f(x)$ can be represented by a MacLaurin series, then

\begin{align}
   f(x)
   &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}x^n\\
   &= f(0)\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{c^n}{n!}x^n\\
   &= f(0)e^{cx}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

For part (b) I'll look at a special case that I think captures all that is needed. Let $I=(0,b).$ Suppose $f$ is differentiable and nonzero on $I,$ with $f'(x) = cf(x), x \in I,$ where $c$ is a nonzero constant. Then $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x) \ne 0.$

Proof: The statements below pertain to all of $I.$ WLOG, $f>0.$ We then have

$$(\ln f)'(x) = f'(x)/f(x) = c.$$

Thus the derivative of $\ln f(x)- cx$ is $0,$ which implies $\ln f(x)- cx = d$ for some constant $d.$ This gives $f(x) = e^{cx+d},$ and the conclusion follows.

Comment: The essential part is to establish $f$ is either identically zero or it is of constant sign. We can't just assume $f$ to be non-zero. Rather it follows from the equation $f' = cf$.

Comment: Suppose the equation is satisfied on some open interval $I,$ $f = 0$ somewhere in $I,$ and $f\not \equiv 0.$ Then $I\setminus \{x\in I: f(x) \ne 0\}$ is nonempty and open in $I.$ Hence it is the union of a countable collection of nonempty open intervals $(a_n,b_n),$ on each of which $f$ is never $0.$ Apply my answer to any one of these intervals to get a contradiction. (Perhaps I should add this to my answer.)