# Is there a real-valued function f different from exp($a^x$) for which f'(x) = a*f(x) for all real x?

Tags: functions

I would like to ask if the question above is true or not and if true, how it can be proved?

Comment: `DSolve[f'[x] == a f[x], f[x], x]` gives only `E^(a x) C[1]` as a solution, i.e. a family of exponentials.

Comment: You just gave the definition of the exponential function.

Comment: Did you mean for the title to read $\exp(ax)$ instead of $\exp(a^x)$?

Comment: Related: [How do we show that the function which is its own derivative is exponential?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2016912/how-do-we-show-that-the-function-which-is-its-own-derivative-is-exponential/2017417).

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with $f'(x) = a f(x)$. Consider the function $g(x) = f(x) e^{-ax}$. Then $g$ is differentiable with derivative
$$g'(x) = f'(x) e^{-ax} + f(x) (-ae^{-ax}) = e^{-ax}(af(x) - af(x)) = 0.$$

But this means that $g$ is a constant function, i.e. $f(x) = C e^{ax}$.