# How can I prove that there is a function that is its own derivative?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

How can I prove that a function that is its own derivative exists? And how can I prove that this function is of the form $a(b^x)$?

Comment: There are probably already a few posts about this problem on this site. For example, [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24f%27(x)%3Df(x)%24&p=1) I was able to find this question: [Proof that $C\exp(x)$ is the only set of functions for which $f(x) = f'(x)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58097).

Comment: 3Blue1Brown actually goes through this in his "Essence of Calculus" videos that are posting on YouTube this week (sorry, but I'm not able to go searching for the link right now).

Comment: The first part's easy - can't you just write down $e^x$? Seriously, though, you don't need to do anything special - all you need to do to prove that "some $x$ exists" is produce an example of $x$.

Comment: See this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031

Comment: One way to prove there exists such a function is to prove that the derivative of the zero function, $f(x) = 0$ for all $x,$ is the zero function.

Comment: How do you define $b^x$?

Comment: @EJoshuaS - the point of this is to prove that the function $e^x$ exists. Thus you cannot use the existence of $e^x$ to prove it.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Fair enough

Comment: Isnt there some 'fixed point theorem' at play here?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

There are two ways you could show it. The harder route would be to prove the existence and uniqueness theorem for ordinary differential equations, thus showing there exists solutions to $y'=y$.

The more direct way would be to just construct the function $e^x$ and show that it's its own derivative. You would start by defining
$$\ln(x) = \int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\, dt$$
and prove that it's a strictly increasing function on $(0,\infty)$ with range $(-\infty, \infty)$. It follows that $\ln(x)$ has an inverse, which we should dub $e^x$. As for finding the derivative of this new and mysterious function: 
$$y=e^x$$
$$\ln(y)=x$$
Taking the $x$ derivative of both sides,
$$\frac{y'}{y} = 1$$
$$\implies y'=y$$
And do show that every function which is its own derivative is a constant multiple of $e^x$, suppose that $f'=f$. Then, noting that $e^x$ is nowhere zero,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{f(x)}{e^x} = \frac{f'(x)e^x-f(x)e^x}{(e^x)^2} = \frac{f(x)e^x-f(x)e^x}{(e^x)^2} = 0$$
Therefore, $$\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$$ is constant since it has a connected domain, and so $f(x) = ce^x$ for some $c$.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to do it without defining the exponential function?

Comment: Like @florence says in the first paragraph of the answer, this follows from the existence of (short-time) solutions to ordinary differential equations, which shows just as well that there is a function $f$ that satisfies the equation $F(x, y, y', \ldots, y^{(m)}) = 0$ for any reasonable function $F$.

Comment: I think it would be fair to first write the function as $\exp (x) $, then find $e=\exp (1) $, and show that the properties of the logarithm imply that $exp (x)=e^x $ for $x $ rational, and then extend to irrational. Also, you omitted the easiest way, which is to define $e^x=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac {x^k}{k!} $.

Comment: Why are $\ln x, e^x$ differentiable? That is worth mentioning at this level.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, the power series approach does not seem easier to me. You would at least have to say that the power series converges uniformly on each compactum and that that implies that you can differentiate (or easier: integrate, then use the fundamental theorem) "under the sum".

Comment: @CarstenS: proving that basic fact about power series is certainly easier than proving both the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and the Inverse Function Theorem, which are required for the "log" approach.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, I think without the Fundamental Theorem you have to actually work to show that uniform convergence implies that you limit and derivative commute. I would not enjoy it. I am not sure about the inverse function theorem, you may be right about that one. Well, it all depends on what one already knows.

Comment: Unfolding the proof of Picard's theorem, you get a construction which isn't too bad: iterate the construction $f \mapsto \lambda x . 1 + \int_0^x f(t)\,dt$, and then prove that for instance on the interval $[-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}]$ the sequence of iterates is uniformly Cauchy and therefore has a uniform limit.

Comment: Oh, and incidentally, it just so happens if you start the iteration with the 0 function, the iterates are the partial sums of the Taylor series for $e^x$.

Comment: @P.B.G. So according to youe question you wan t to prove that the solutions have the form $y=ab^x$, but according to your comment you do not want to introduce the exponential form? That may really be ambitious ...

Comment: @P.B.G.: without defining the exponential function? What does "$b^x$" mean to you?

Answer (score 42):

$f(x) = 0$ is trivially its own derivative, and is of the form $a(b^x)$ for $a=0$ and any positive $b$. That's all we need to solve the problem posed.

Comment: Good example, producing an example is sometimes the easiest way to prove this kind of thing. $e^x$ would also work, obviously.

Comment: Eh, some questioners may find it charming to point out trivialities coming from minor deficiencies in the question posed.  Others might not, and may get frustrated and disappointed.  Especially if it is in an answer (highly upvoted!) and not a comment.

Comment: The point isn't to be charming; the point is to solve the problem. If this problem showed up on a test, I would give this answer and use the time I saved to check my work, and I would be frustrated and disappointed if I *didn't* answer this way and then realized later that I could have.

Comment: It does not solve the OP's problem, @user2357112; you know that, so don't pretend you don't.  You are smart enough to know what the OP is looking for, so you can simply make a note that they should exclude the trivial solution by positing y(0)=1 in a comment.

Comment: But it does solve the problem. Sometimes problems are easy. Easy problems arise naturally in a wide variety of contexts, on their own or as part of the solution to harder problems, and recognizing when a problem is easy and not being blind to the easy answer is a crucial mathematical skill.

Comment: This answer is incomplete even for the question as written (as usually understood). If you answer this on a test you may wake up to a bad surprise. "this function" refers to a generic solution; granted it would be better if phrased differently.

Comment: @quid Any math teacher who marks as incorrect a succinct and valid proof based on the exact wording of the requirement (such as this answer) was erroneously given a degree of any sort in mathematics, IMHO. While it is helpful to keep the spirit of mathematics in ones mind while practicing it (by spirit, I mean the idea that the technical details are not the only important parts of mathematics), what math is really *about* is assiduously holding oneself to obeying the structures of an organized system of thought. A student finding such an elegant solution to one of my problems earns my respect.

Comment: @guest I myself have posed problems such as the one in this question, knowing that there is the "expected" answer as well as one or more "trivial" answers with the express purpose of understanding when a student is a good student or a *mathematician*. The former will show that $e^x$ is its own derivative. The latter will answer with the zero function. See: http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2208

Comment: @ToddWilcox it seems amply clear that "this function" is intended as "such a function" or to be still more clear "every such function." Or differently the "is" is a "must be." That this is not clear in OP is likely  an error of translating and/or paraphrasing the original source. For the context of this site, this is not answer. If the wording was on an exam, I'd say it is ambiguous enough that the correct course of action would be to ask the instructor what was intended. Put differently there is no exact wording of the requirements to begin with.

Comment: @ToddWilcox further, it is not very clear to me what's your authority  when asserting "what math is *really* about" or which "students are *mathematician*." In my opinion it is a quality of a mathematician to grasp the essence of a situation and to deal with accordingly, as opposed to focusing *solely* on a formality. Differently, in your comic I think the roles are rather reverted.

Comment: @quid Why do you interpret the question as if it was a poem?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski because it is ill-formed as written, and thus needs interpretation. There is no (particular) function that could be referred to at the point where "this function" appears in the text. It's more than a bit ironic that those insisting on the importance of taking things as written,  organized system of thoughts, etc., seem not to care about this issue.

Comment: @guest "You are smart enough to know what the OP is looking for". **Knowing better what somebody else wants is patronizing.** The OP had all means to tell us. It is rude to assume he or she isn't smart enough to do so. People are not born with the knowledge of trivial solutions so they may want them also, we don't know it beforehand. Even if we all agreed the trivial solution is enough so it was the only answer here, and the OP realized it's not what he or she really wants, then the OP could ask *another* question with additional condition to get non-trivial solution or every possible one.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski once again, the original post is ambiguous as written. If you disagree, please explain what "this function" would refer to. (Note that the post does **not** say "Give an example of a function [...]; prove that this function [...]". A proof of existence may well not yield any example at all.) The reasonable course of action is thus to assume the more general/interesting version, and include mention of the special case/other interpretation as a side remark.

Comment: @quid "A proof of existence may well not yield any example at all". True. But what it does is proving that at least one such-and-such function exists. This function (whatever it is, known to us or not) is "this function" the OP refers to. And you're right: the post does not say "give an example of a function". It also *does not* forbid this angle of attack. Giving a valid example is an excellent proof of existence, **isn't it?** Sometimes giving an example is hard and other methods may be easier (including ones that don't yield any example), sometimes it's easy. In this case it was easy.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I have nothing against the proof of existence given in this answer. Please read carefully my objections. The problem comes later. It is that, as you say, "this function" can only refer to some *unspecified* function that is it's own derivative. *Therefore* one needs to establish the claim on the form of such a function for an *unspecified* function, that is, every function that is its own derivative. Not only one particular one. The objection would also apply  to an answer that says $e^x$ has the property and is of that form.

Comment: @quid I would easily take your course of thought in the first place, if only the OP wrote "every such a function" instead of "this function". However I got your point when I asked myself the same question ending with "…of the form $ax+b$".

Comment: @quid The question as stated is "How can I prove that a function which is its own derivative exists? And how can I prove that this function is in the form of $a(b^x)$?" For questions that merely ask whether such a function exists, demonstrating even a single function that fits those criteria is proof that such a function exists. By trying to psychoanalyze the questioner, you are making the solution more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: @Abion47 'For questions that merely ask whether such a function exists, demonstrating even a single function that fits those criteria is proof that such a function exists.' Indeed. This is was not my objection. You seem to miss the point. It is: OP is not clearly formulated (concerning the *second* part of the question).  It is odd to chose a trivial interpretation over more interesting ones (mentioning the trivial one as an aside).

Comment: @quid Whether or not you approve of the trivial answer does not make the answer any less valid. Also, you are making assumptions as to what it is that OP wants. If OP wanted a proof that, say, shows _all_ functions which are their own derivatives were in the form $a(b^x)$, then he would've asked for that, or in the very least he would've clarified. The fact that he chose an answer that is just a more thorough version of this answer exists makes your objection largely unfounded.

Comment: @Abion47 "The fact that he chose an answer that is just a more thorough version of this answer exists makes your objection largely unfounded." I have no idea what you are referring to. Anyway, the accepted answer shows precisely that every solution must be of the form $ce^x$. Note 'And do show that every function which is its own derivative is [...]' On the first part of your comment. OP is ambiguous; it is not coherent strictly as written (for details see above). The question is just which interpretation one chooses, a meaningful one or a trivial one.

Comment: @quid: "Anyway, the accepted answer shows precisely that every solution must be of the form $ce^x$" - actually, it doesn't. It skips over any justification for saying that the inverse of the integral used is of the form $a(b^x)$, instead jumping straight to using $e^x$ notation, and it doesn't do anything to prove that solutions not of the form $a(b^x)$ can't exist.

Comment: I'll skip replying to the first part, let  me focus on: "and it doesn't do anything to prove that solutions not of the form a(bx) can't exist" since this is my main issue. I can only assume you did not read that answer to the end. It takes any solution $f$, considers the derivative of $f/e^x$. Shows that it is $0$ and thus concludes that the quotient $f/e^x$ is constant and therefore $f$ is of the form $ce^x$. To reiterate, the $f$ is an arbitrary solution and nothing but $f' = f$ is used, and it follows it is of the form $ce^x$  What is not clear about that?

Comment: If your issue is about the "precisely." I did not mean to insist on the fact that that answer was particularly precise or detailed (though I find it alright). The "precisely" was intended as a counter-point to the mysterious allegation that "he chose an answer that is just a more thorough version of this answer exists makes your objection largely unfounded", when the accepted answer does contain a paragraph whose sole purpose is to establish (i.e., is precisely about)  what I find missing in this answer. I feel that part is also rather precise, but that wasn't the point I meant to make.

Comment: @quid: Ah, whoops, it does indeed show that all solutions must be a constant multiple of the solution given. I didn't read the part in the middle carefully enough where it introduces $f$. My mistake.

Comment: The phrase "this function" should indeed be understood as "every such a function" **to avoid a subtle trap**. Consider "this function returns $0$ for $x=0$". The negation is "this function *doesn't* return $0$ for $x=0$". You can find an example to "prove" the first, and *another* example to "prove" the second. Now it's easy to say "Proven! This function returns $0$ for $x=0$ *and* this function doesn't return $0$ for $x=0$". With "every such a function" approach you can prove none of the two statements and there's no contradiction. The root problem is "this function" isn't an exact phrase.

Answer (score 21):

**An intuitive answer**:

For smooth functions and "small" $h$, we have

$$f'(x)\approx\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}h.$$

Then $f'(x)=f(x)$ yields

$$f(x+h)\approx(1+h)f(x),$$
and
$$f(x+2h)\approx(1+h)f(x+h)\approx(1+h)^2f(x),$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f(x+nh)\approx(1+h)^nf(x).$$

Now with $nh=1$,

$$f(x+1)\approx \left(1+\frac1n\right)^n f(x),$$ which should ring a bell.

Comment: I guess you want $f(x+y)=f(x)e^y$, not just the case $y=1$. On another note, I have some distrust of these "intuitive" reasonings because when I was studying physics in another life these things crept everywhere; thing is, whenever I would try to do the same, my results were always wrong. So I always got the feeling  that one does these kind of computations because they already work by other reasons, but that it is extremely easy to stray from the "correct" path.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: the answer covers any $nh$, but this is unimportant. The goal was to show the appearance of $e$.

Comment: This can be seen as solving the differential equation $y' = y$ using Euler's method with $n$ steps of size $1/n$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: of course.

Answer (score 15):

If you postulate a solution to $y=y'$ of the form $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k$, by the equality of the power series on both sides of the equality one gets $$ a_{k+1}=(k+1)a_k,$$and then one deduces that $$a_k=\frac{a_0}{k!},\ \ \ \ k=1,2,\ldots.$$So $$y(x)=a_0\,\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}.$$One can then focus on the case where $a_0=1$, say $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}$. Define $e=g(1)$. Using the series one can show that $$ g(x+y)=g(x)g(y).$$ It follows that $$\tag{1}g(x)=e^x$$ for $x$ rational. As $g$ is continuous (infinitely differentiable, even), it has to be $e^x=g(x)$ for irrational $x$, too. Thus
$$
y(x)=a_0\,e^x.
$$

Comment: Possibly a new learner needs the recurrence relationship on `a[k]` explicitly written out to see why `a[k]=1/k!` follows from the assumption that the function being expanded is its own derivative.  Similarly, for exposition I'd write `f(x)=...` instead of `exp(x)`.  The danger I suppose, is that then you'd just be doing a bunch of future visitors homework for them as they could copy/paste the entirety and turn it in.

Comment: Yes, good points.

Comment: This is an excellent answer! It doesn't require knowledge about $e$ or the natural logarithm, and even helps explain what they are. It just needs some power series machinery and the binomial theorem. +1