# Find all holomorphic functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ at $c=0$ that satisfy $f(x)=f'(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find all holomorphic functions at $c=0$ , $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfy $f(x)=f'(x)$

From my understanding the only function that satisfies that condition is $f(x)=e^x$. (?) How do I show that? I want to show it using its Taylor series obviously but am not sure how to formally prove this.
Thank you :)

Comment: Holomorphic functions are defined over $\Bbb C$...

Comment: Yes, though we have yet to study calculus over the complex field.

Comment: what do you mean with "at $c = 0$"?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank you! will read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's also a cute trick we can borrow from the differential equations handbook, one that we can use without having to assume $f$ is analytic. Suppose the equation
$$f'(x) - f(x) = 0$$
holds true for all $x$. Then this implies that,
$$f'(x) e^{-x} - f(x) e^{-x} = 0.$$
But, using the product rule, the left hand side turns into
$$(e^{-x} f(x))' = 0.$$
It follows therefore that, for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$e^{-x} f(x) = c \implies f(x) = c e^{-x}.$$
This is just the integrating factor technique from first order linear ODEs!

Answer (score 5):

It's Taylor series at $0$ would be $f(0)\cdot \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n!}$ since all the derivatives are $f(x)$...

Comment: Ok thank you. Is that all I need to show? Yes, I'm guessing it was a lame question then...

Comment: @Noy Perel  that is the power series for $e^x$...  it's unique...  of course not a lame question...

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do it this way:
$$f(x)=f'(x)$$
If $f(x) \neq 0$:
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=1$$
$$\left[\log(f(x))\right]'=1$$
$$\left[\log(f(x))\right]'=[x+c]'$$
$$\log(f(x))=x+c$$
$$\exp(\log(f(x)))=\exp(x+c)$$
$$f(x)=c\exp(x)$$