# $f(x) = \ln(x)f'(x)$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I would like to find a differentiable $f:[1,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfying:

$$f(x) = \ln(x)f'(x)$$.

My work:

> We have $f(1) = 0$ and $f(e)=f^k(e)$. A Taylor series centered at $x_0=e$ gives us the following polynomial:
>   $$f(e)+f(e)(x-e)+f(e)\frac{1}{2}(x-e)^2 \dots$$
>   $$=f(e) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(x-e)^k}{k!}$$
>   although I don't see how this might help me, and I also am not sure how else to approach this problem. Does the condition $f(e)=f^k(e)$ force $f(x)$ to be $e^x$, which would contradict $f(x)=\ln(x)f'(x)$, and thus no $f$ exists? I wouldn't think so, although I know that $Ae^x$ is the unique solution to $f(x)=f'(x)$ from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1291511/are-the-any-non-trivial-functions-where-fx-fx-not-of-the-form-aex).

Comment: If
$$\frac{1}{\ln(x)}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}$$
then
$$
\int \frac{1}{\ln(x)}=\int \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\ln(f(x))
$$
The problem is that the LHS does not have an expression in elementary terms.

Comment: @Reveillark The question does not ask for an elementary function $f$, just a differentiable $f$. One should perhaps focus on the existence.

Comment: @Reveillark But shouldn't you take care of the pole at $x = 1$?

Comment: @WhatsUp Hmmm yeah you might be right, you run into trouble there. I think there might be something to salvage in my original comment, so I'll leave it up. The constantly $0$ function definitely works though :P

Comment: @Reveillark Alright... you win with zero...

Comment: @WhatsUp I do not think that one can really take care of the pole: the solution to the differential equation is $ce^{\text{li}(x)}$ which has a cuspid at $x=1$ for all the $c\neq 0$.

Comment: How do you draw $f(e)=f^k(e)$, which seems to be a wrong identity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written, the equation has a nasty singularity at $x=1$ and this is reflected in the solution with the integral logarithm (see Claude's answer).

Around $x=1$ we can write $\log x\approx x-1$, leading to the solution $f(x)\approx|x-1|$. Hence we substitute $f(x)=(x-1)g(x)$, giving us

$$\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}=1-\frac{\log x}{x-1}.$$

With the kind help of WA,

$$\log g(x)+c=x+\text{Li}_2(1-x)=x+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(1-x)^k}{k^2}.$$

($\text{Li}_2$ is the dilogarithm function, which is quite smooth.) The given series converges in $[0,2]$. Values elsewhere can be obtained by these identities: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function#Identities.

Answer (score 2):

As Caffeine commented
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac1{\log(x)}\implies f(x)=C e^{\text{li}(x)}=C e^{\text{Ei}(\log(x))}$$

If you look for a series expansion of $e^{\text{li}(x)}$ around $x=e$, it is given by
$$e^{\text{Ei}(1)}\left(1+(x-e)+\frac{(e-1) }{2 e}(x-e)^2+\frac{e^2-3e+3}{6 e^3}(x-e)^3+ O\left((x-e)^4\right)\right)$$ where $e^{\text{Ei}(1)}\approx 6.65333$