# On the qualitative behaviour of functions of the form $f’(x) = f(x)$ as x decreases

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Pretend that you don’t know about the function $ e^x$ (so pretend to erase it and everything you know about it from your memory, for argument’s sake).

You want to draw graphs of functions that satisfy $f’(x) = f(x)$. Not precisely, but you want to know it’s qualitative properties.

$f(x) = 0 \forall x$ is a trivial solution, so let’s put this to one side.

Now you also quickly realise that if $f(x) > 0$ for some $x,\ $ then the following qualitative behaviour of the function $f(x)$ must be true: both $f(x)$ and $f’(x)$ must be strictly positive and increasing as $x {\to} \infty$. You realised this by drawing a small straight line of gradient 1 when $f(x) = 1$ and then  $f’(x) = 1.1$ just to the right, when $f(x) = 1.1$ etc etc.

Are there any arguments- graphical, using calculus and continuity and any other tools you might have, to determine whether or not $f(c)=0 $ for some $ c \in \mathbb{R}$ as $x$ decreases? If such a $c$ does exist, then it follows that $f(x) = 0 \forall x<c$ also, since:

if $f(a) < 0$ for some $a<c$ then $\exists b $ with $a<b<c$ such that $f’(b) > 0$, so $f’(b) \neq f(b)$, a contradiction to the original condition. A similar argument can be made to show that $f(d) > 0$ for some $ d<c$ leads to a contradiction.

But it’s not clear to me how you can argue that the graph *wouldn’t* attain f(x) = 0 for some x. I don’t see why our graph can’t *look like* for example, the piecewise curve $y=0$ for $x < 0$ and $y= x^4$ for $x \geq 0$. Can an argument be made for why this isn’t possible this in a similar vein to one of my arguments/lines of reasoning above?

Comment: See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem

Comment: The key to figure out here is that if $f(c) =0$ then $f(x) =0$ for all $x$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1292586/72031 for details.

Comment: What about the piecewise defined function $f(x) = 0, x = 0; f(x) = e^x, x \neq 0$?

Comment: @Lili FN what about it? Did you read the question?

Comment: Yes, sorry that was a very unclear comment. With regards to the previous comment, I was wondering what extra assumptions would need to be made (e.g. analyticity) to be able to conclude that if $f(x)=f′(x) \forall x$, then $ \exists c:f(c)=0 \implies f(x)=\forall x$.

Comment: You mean $\ \implies f(x)=0\  \forall x$ ? Yeah, that's the point, no extra assumptions need to be made. Paramanand Singh proves this in his answer in the link above. [So his answer to that question is also an answer to my question].