# Find all functions that satisfy that $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = e^{x}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I used the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus and I obtained that $f(x) = e^{x}$ but when I integrate f, it results in $e^{x} - 1$.

Comment: There are no functions which satisfy $\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt = e^{x}$. However, a very common definition of $\text{exp}(x)$ is the unique function such that $f′(x)=f(x)$ and $f(0)=1$ as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58097/proof-that-c-expx-is-the-only-set-of-functions-for-which-fx-fx).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no such functions.  Note that taking $x=0$ on the left gives $0$ while on the right it gives $1$.

Comment: Why FTC doesn't apply?

Comment: @Salihcyilmaz  because the initial equation is internally contradictory.  If you start from a false premise you can deduce whatever you want.

Comment: Ah, i see now, thanks.