# Prove that if $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, then there exist a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=ce^x$ for all $x$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I have the following exercise:

> Prove that if $f'(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$, then there exist a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=ce^x$ for all $x$

My attempt:

Let's consider the function $g(x)=f(x)-ae^x$, $g'(x)=f'(x)-ae^x=f(x)-ae^x=0$ then $g$ is constant. Then $g(x)=k=f(x)-ae^x$, then $f(x)=ce^x$

I think it is incorrect because of how I get to the $f(x)=ce^x$ part. I would really appreciate your help with this problem, thank you.

Comment: Why is $g'(x)=f'(x)-ae^x=f(x)-ae^x=0$ ?

Comment: See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58097/42969 for a correct solution. More similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/58097?lq=1.

Comment: Ah man, I'm using what I want to try ...

Comment: Thanks you @MartinR!